# Is it possible to use CSS flexbox to shrink/stretch content on both axes, vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

It's my understanding that flexbox containers and their child items flex fully along only one axis, depending on the value of the `flex-direction` property, `row` or `column`. With a "row" container, you can stretch and shrink the width of the container and the individual boxes it contains, but the content in those boxes does not grow or shrink to match. On the other hand, resizing a window vertically does cause content to resize accordingly. (I think the situation is vice versa with "column" containers, though I haven't tried them alone.)

So my questions:

1. Do I have that right? I've read through many nice blog posts on flexboxes, but none covered this characteristic explicitly as a main 'feature.'
2. Is there a *flexbox-only* workaround, some arrangement of rows-inside-columns or the other way around, maybe with specific properties set special ways?

I tried putting a columnar container inside a flexbox belonging to a row container, and then putting text into that, but I saw no change in resizing behavior--the text still resizes only when the window/viewbox is resized vertically, not horizontally. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/JoanEliot/pen/BayVqpW?editors=1100).

(About the example: first, I apologize for extraneous properties or properties set to random-ish values, but I was trying anything and everything. I tried to pare them back without messing up the demo but I'm sure there's much to improve. The svg logo on the left is just in a top-level flexbox in the main container for that row--it behaves as expected, shrinking/growing only with vertical window resizes. I put a hidden logo in a third box on the right so with equal-width boxes on either side, the text between them comes out centered in the viewbox, if you don't use shrink too much side to side. Maybe there's a less kludgy way with flexbox to a row with centered text and a logo on the left.)

Comment: Text does not resize according to it's container size. I'm unclear on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Text *does* resize as the container gets taller or shorter when you resize a window vertically. Images do too. But when you resize a window horizontally, a flexbox row-type container's height doesn't change--the row isn't scaled to ensure that it fits in the available space, and once any unused space is removed, contents overflow either off the window or to a new row. I guess I'm saying I'm trying make the container scale as necessary so that it always fits fully, with all of its child boxes, within the window horizontally. Just trying to figure out how flexbox works.